# Unexpected action of jq select filter

Tags: select, null, jq, is-empty

I have been using jq for quite a while, but some behaviour today has surprised me:

I expected this:

```
 echo '{"Name":"NAME","Tags":[{"Key":"KEY","Value":"HASH"}]}' \
 | jq '{"name": .Name, "hash": (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="hash")|.Value)}'
```

to produce this:

```
{
   "name": "NAME",
   "hash": null
}
```

but instead, it filters out the entire object from the output completely.

As a sanity check changing the filter to a value that does match as follows::

```
 echo '{"Name":"NAME","Tags":[{"Key":"KEY","Value":"HASH"}]}' \
| jq '{"name": .Name, "hash": (.Tags[]|select(.Key=="KEY")|.Value)}'
```

produces the expected output:

```
{
   "name": "NAME",
   "hash": "HASH"
}
```

The output of the first case, `select(.Key=="hash")`, is surprising to me since the select filter is meant to be acting on the stream produced by .Tags[] and not the entire input stream.

How do I express what I want to express, which is if there is no matching Tag, the "hash" property of the output object should be set to null?

I am using jq 1.6 on OSX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a part of a filter produces `empty`, it will suck in everything that is compund to it.

Solution: Don't let it produce `empty`. One way would be to give the `select` filter an alternative: `select(.Key=="hash") // null`

```sh
jq '{"name": .Name, "hash": (.Tags[] | select(.Key=="hash") // null | .Value)}'
```

```json
{
  "name": "NAME",
  "hash": null
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/sWVjUpH-xz)

Comment: I didn't realise empty propagated like that, but I do now. Thank you!